# How to turn on the balloon popup with the calculated results of the selected part of the formula?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I accidentally switched it off and could not find how to turn it back on.

Answer (score 2):

Press F9 (Turn on formula preview)

Answer (score 1):

If, by any means, you seem to be unable to get the preview of your highlighted formula to pop (even when pressing F9), try zomming in and out (a lot) in Chrome's settings (**Ctrl + mousewheel**)

P.S.: You might have to **put your cursor out of the Spreadsheet zone** in order to change the zoom %.